# Copying file/directory is treated as a Virus - Update App

Tags: c#, .net, copy, auto-update, virus

the following code in my program is treated as a Virus by Kaspersky.

Any tips to solve this please?

What I am doing is **updating the application**. I create a temp folder, download the files in there, then I delete the files of the original folder and finnaly copy the files from the temp to the original folder. This last step is being treated as a virus by kaspersky.

```
private void CopiarPasta(string origem, string destino)
    {
        //copy the directories
        foreach (string dirPath in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(origem, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(dirPath.Replace(origem, destino));
        }

        //copy the files
        foreach (string newPath in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(origem, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(origem, destino));
            }
            //I can't kill vshost32.exe
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Whenever you're saying `catch{}` you're probably shooting at your own leg

Comment: hehe. I agree, but I believe this is not important right now.

Comment: Did you tried the last step by overwrite `parameter` set to true `File.Copy(newPath, newPath.Replace(origem, destino), true)` instead of deleting and copying?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel, I just tried, but the problem still.

Comment: May I ask how you came to the conclusion that this bit of code specifically is problematic with Kaspersky?

Comment: @tnw, because if I remove this code, the anti virus doesn't show a dialog.

Comment: I also tried another code for copying a folder, and Kaspersky continues to dialog.

Comment: Guys, if noone knows how to solve it. I will change the strategy. I will download the file and ask the user to save it somewhere, and manually extract and run the executable. =P.